# Decision and PhD. Take a once-in-a-lifetime opportunity or pursue a life dream

Tags: phd, masters, advisor, mathematics, computer-science

Young male student soon to receive an Engineering Degree unsure about the next steps to follow. Undecided whether to go for a PhD directly or do a Master studies first (if he goes for the Master, he will first have to do a thesis work anyway). Has to decide between a PhD position to which he has promising chances to get a scholarship funded by a top company in the world, or apply for a prestigious scholarship for a Master's degree to which he stands good chances and that could probably lead to study in a top US university. His goal is to study at a top university and do research at the highest level. Seeks advice from experienced or knowledgeable advisors and academics about what to do next.

Comment: *I studied about 12+ hours a day, 340 to 350 days a year, for 5 consecutive years.* Does this include class time? Honestly, I'd prefer you go for the Fulbright, if nothing else other than to take a break from studying so much.

Comment: One thing jumps out at me most - the idea that if you apply to one position you are obligated to accept it, even if you get other competing offers. While this is true in trying to get a single article published, for instance, that is the only place I've ever in my life seen such a thing, so I would immediately pound on this part of the problem because it might utterly free up your mind to apply to both (and more) and let the chips fall where they may. In applying for Phds, post-docs, internships, jobs, running for presidential nomination, and scholarships, you are allowed to not accept.

Comment: @BrianDHall Good point! I'll definitely check that out and update as I get an answer.

Comment: @PALEN None of us are Terence Tao. People do become PhDs in their late 50s. Academia and degrees are not a race.

Comment: I'm just guessing this UK MS funded PhD is the one at Warwick.  If so, then No it is not top, but is much better than "middling" and would certainly give you excellent opportunities to pursue research at the highest level and build a research career.

Comment: @Compass Totally agreed. If you do it as a race, you're doing it for the wrong reasons. But if you're putting a lot of time because you love what you do, it isn't wasted time, is it? So, why not? However, the mentioned rythm is unsustainable and from now on I'd like to dedicate time to other things (e.g. social ones) as well.

Comment: @Compass: there's nothing wrong with studying that much; it works for some people, at least for me.

Comment: @user1997744 12 hours of study a day for 350 days a year for 5 years is *a lot of studying*. That's 4200 hours a year. A full-time employee works approximately 2000 hours a year.

Answer (score 4):

It seems like you're choosing between

1. A (nearly) guaranteed PhD offer at a middling university.
2. A fully funded master's program that you *may or may not* be accepted to, but may offer you the opportunity to jump to a better PhD program *if* you get the Fulbright scholarship and perform well in your master's.

Some factors you may consider are

1. If you take the master's offer you will spend a lot of time preparing for a PhD.  You will need to perform extra well for two years to secure your letters of recommendation, and it will look bad if you don't accomplish anything significant during that time.  In the end you might not get into your school of choice, and then you will have worked very hard for no visible gain.  How confident are you that you can (1) get the scholarship, and (2) perform consistently well once you're actually there?
2. A master's degree will give you more background in computer science, and you will learn more about theoretical CS than "it involves both programming and mathematics."  A *lot* of things involve both programming and mathematics, and getting more experience (in coursework and research) will let you better evaluate your options before jumping into a long commitment.  Most theoretical CS students I know entered their PhD program knowing they wanted to study "approximation algorithms," "cryptography," etc, not just "theoretical CS" or "some field that involves both programming and math."

   It's also kind of a red flag that you're undecided between a PhD and a master's, and I think before you go for a PhD you should have a stronger opinion on this.  If you are uncertain about your career and your research area you will be at a significant disadvantage compared to your classmates who aren't.
3. If your first choice is the PhD offer, you can easily apply to both and turn down the Master's offer, but if your first choice is the Master's offer, it would be awkward to apply to both and turn down the PhD offer.

Comment: 1. About point 1, I'm not afraid of doing a master and not be successful enough to be accepted for a Phd. That'll mean I may not be suited for it.
2. I took a course in theoretical CS and know more than that "it involves both programming and mathematics" and also know and LIKE the research project I've been offered. But yeah, I also like many other CS topics - though one can't know it all! How does one determine whether to take a PhD topic or not?
3. I'd like to know why would it be awkward. Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

You should ask yourself what is your dream destination, and make decisions that will lead you to the destination. Is studying at a US University a destination or point in a journey?

If I read your post correctly you are already accepted to UK. So, on one hand you have the opportunity to go in UK, or on the other hand possibly be accepted for Fulbright which will maybe get you to US. What is the alternative if Fulbright/US do not pan out?

Last note, never underestimate the value of a good advisor, even from a lesser University. Attending the best school with an adviser who will not advocate for you, limits your options later on. Again, what you choose depends what your destination is.

Comment: I'm not already accepted to the UK university. For me what is more important is a place where I can excel. For example, if you go to Stanford, you don't have to worry about anything other than working hard - you have resources and outstanding academic help, also know that by the prestige of the university, your work will be taken into account. Also, I believe the US lifestyle fits me better.